# Got message from console "Duplicate names route"

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-i18n

I using with nuxt.js and `nuxt-i18n` to use locales.

But I always got this message on console by duplicate that even I using nuxt generate from folder structure.

Message:

[image]

Routing:

[image]

Sample of config:

```
modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    ['nuxt-i18n', {
      locales: [
        { name: 'ภาษาไทย', code: 'th', iso: 'th-TH', file: 'th.js' },
        { name: 'English', code: 'th', iso: 'en-US', file: 'en.js' }
      ],
      defaultLocale: 'th',
      lazy: true,
      langDir: 'lang/'
    }]
  ],
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have same code for both of your locales.

> code: 'th'

Change english code to en and it should fix the issue

Comment: Oh, seem I just blind. Thanks :)